# onPause, onResume, onStop, onStart, etc, not firing - life cycle?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have two application that work together on a tablet. Im noticing that if the user backs out of one application and the next time the app is opened oncreate is called, but if they hit home and then go back oncreate is not called..  I have also notice that onPause, onStop, onResume are NEVER being called..  I need to some how make sure that the app finishes if the user hits home..

```
@Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pause MED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "stopped MED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart () {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Restart MED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start MED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume () {

        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "RESUME MED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent currentIntent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle extras = currentIntent.getExtras();
```

or another option is if my other app can check to see if the app is open and close it..

please help

Comment: Use Log statements instead of Toasts. The Toasts will start to behave strange when they get stacked up. Logs have no blocking time so it isn't a problem and you'll be able to see exactly what order things are being called in. Also that is how the home button is meant to function as @PaulG pointed out.

Comment: Toasts aside, would you post more of your activity code since what you have provided shouldn't violate the lifecycle?

Answer (score 5):

The home button does not kill the application, it should call onPause() when hit and onResume() when you come back to the app afterwards. Instead of using toast, why not print to the log?? I'm sure those methods are being fired. It might just be that the Toast is not showing up because these methods are called before or after the UI can be modified.

Also something I've noticed from experience that might seem a little strange: onResume() is fired even when you're launching a fresh instance of the app (not coming back after hitting home button)... I'm pretty sure onResume() is fired whenever you're activity gains the foreground, no matter if it was already running in the background or not.

Comment: NOPE THEY ARE NOT!!!  onPause()  is Not ever getting called? trust me, i have a log and a toast.. neither is showing

Answer (score 1):

Your app fires onCreate() after pushing the home button because you are destroying your app when you call `finish()` in onPause().  It must be created again after it has been destroyed.  I also believe that this causes the unexpected behavior with your Toasts since you have destroyed its context.